# Node.js - webrtc peer?

Tags: node.js, webrtc

Since node uses javascript, can it act as a webrtc peer?

Can I then encode it as a VP8 stream and broadcast to all other peers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use node.js as a WebRTC peer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227143/use-node-js-as-a-webrtc-peer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebRTC is a browser API rather than being part of Javascript, so it'd need to be implemented as a Node module.

There are projects to build this though. Check this out:

http://blog.appfog.com/new-horizons-in-node-js-app-js-and-webrtc/

Comment: Can't find anything about using node as a peer in that link, only about using node for simplifying connection between browser peers. Please correct me if i'm wrong and specify which section you are referring to in particular.