# Use node.js as a WebRTC peer?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, p2p, webrtc

What modules are in existence to use node.js as a peer in WebRTC?  I'd like to use WebRTC in a more client/server fashion than P2P for its apparent ability to send packets unreliably. (AKA, I don't want the huge delay TCP makes by guaranteeing packet arrival with data in order)

If I have to use a stripped-down browser page as a server, that would perhaps work... however, it would really be sub-optimal.  Node.js would make things much smoother, and probably more reliable too.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js WebRTC client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872712/node-js-webrtc-client)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Erizo component of [Licode](https://github.com/ging/licode/tree/master/erizo_controller) (WebRTC MCU). It has a stream controller and webrtc controller written in c++ with a js interface. It might help you getting a idea or two.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a Node implementation of WebRTC, with the exception of MediaStreams.

https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc

Answer (score 1):

There is a c++ interface for WebRTC. WebRTC is based on the libjingle project but uses the JSEP (Javascript Session Establishment Protocol) instead of XMPP for sending STUN/TURN information for NAT tunneling. The two projects were in the process of being merged when I looked at this a while back so compiling/linking it was a PITA. This may have been improved last year.

The goal would be to expose the [native API](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/native-apis) for WebRTC as a node module with the [node addon api](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) and package it as an npm module that works like the in-browser API. The cross-browser [polyfill](http://www.webrtc.org/interop) will show you how it should look.

There's a lot of cool stuff you could do with this (call recording, SIP connectors, .torrent extensions to the browser, etc.) I really encourage you to try this!

Answer (score 0):

The most relevant package i've found was http://js-platform.github.io/node-webrtc/ i managed to build it and play with it a little bit... The developer is very helpful, i think it's your best bet right now

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use [libjingle](https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/index) or [licode/erizo](http://lynckia.com/licode/). Both of them require compilation but erizo provides a NodeJS interface. Libjingle was created by Google.

Unfortunately, you have to compile each library and there are *no* binary packages for Debian, Ubuntu or other platforms.

Answer (score -4):

Take a look at [PeerJS: Simple peer-to-peer with WebRTC](http://peerjs.com/).

You need [PeerJS-server](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server) for signaling.

The guide: http://peerjs.com/

Comment: Sorry, but WebSockets don't quite use the same protocol as WebRTC.  Thanks for answering, though!

Comment: WebSockets use TCP. A similar solution for WebRTC which allows the same functionality as WebSockets except via UDP would be optimal.

Answer (score -6):

I used Node js with socket io and have success with it

There are many tutorials online

Comment: Socket.io is one way to communicate bidirectionally between the client and the server, but it doesn't, as far as I know, use WebRTC. Besides, Socket.io, as far as I know, only supports TCP-based transports, which is exactly why WebRTC was chosen.

Comment: does not address media transmission